# How to hide upper right corner advanced search box from sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

We are using sharepoint 2007.sharepoint 
How do I hide the advanced search box which is in the upper right corner of the sharepoint site,but not from all site pages but only from partiular single page

Thanks and Regards,
Rushikesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search box is in the masterpage as a delegate control, heres an example of how to hide it via code http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/sharepoint2010programming/thread/78199ea4-d54b-4aee-8b93-4017d11e2995